# how to echo an array of varriable in a page?

Tags: php, arrays, dump

I am just starting learning codes and am writing some codes to echo an array and it give me this error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ogmt\rest_server_api.php on line 62" HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS?
This is my code:

```
   if($Result1){
    // script to get business no, amount & merchant id,output to merchant page
      $query="SELECT * FROM customer_order WHERE insert_time=(SELECT max(order_time)from customer_order)";
      $result=mysql_query($query);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $amount=$row['amount'];
          $id=$row['merchant_id'];
          $payment_mode=$row['mobile_service'];
          switch($payment_mode){               
           case 'TIGO-PESA':
            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='TIGO-PESA'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
                 $data=array(
                   'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                   'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                   'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                   'Merchant ID'=>$id
                   );
                   }break;

            case 'M-PESA':
            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='M-PESA'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
                 $data=array(
                   'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                   'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                   'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                   'Merchant ID'=>$id
                   );
                   }break;
            case 'AIRTEL-MONEY':
            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobile_client WHERE mobile_service='AIRTEL-MONEY'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
                 $data=array(
                   'Business no'=>$row1['business_no'],
                   'Payment Mode'=>$payment_mode,
                   'Total Amount Tsh'=>$amount,
                   'Merchant ID'=>$id
                    );
                   }break;

           default:
           $data=array('error'=>"no payment mode selected");        
        }
     }
           foreach( $data as $value ){
              echo $value;
                 }      
             }
            else{
      echo "wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: try using mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 3):

you can use print_r() to print the array. like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

if $data is an array.
So you can debug it by yourself.

**Note that first declare $data as array at the top of script.**
like: `$data = array();`

Comment: I use your code and the the error is no more.. but this time it does not print anything

Comment: @maro if it now print empty array then please check; are you getting any data from database?

Comment: The problem is resolved, Ts seems there was an error in my query. Thank you guys..

Comment: @maro and also please don't forget to approve the right answer if you find it helpful, because it will help others to find solution of related problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`print_r()`](http://PHP.net/print_r), but it does not always output the type. It is most useful when you already know that the variable holds an array.

Use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) here instead. You may have to use a `pre` element, as arslaan suggested. With `var_dump()` and the Xdebug extension enabled, you do not have to do that either and the output will be highlighted.